# SELECT one value WHERE ther is a min value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select `LOC_LOC_ID` with the minimum value for the two columns.

Any ideas?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    LOC_LOC_ID as S, 
    MIN(LWWKS_TOTAL_SALES_VAL) as V, 
    MIN(LWWKS_TOTAL_SALES_QTY) as Q
FROM 
    Apollo.dbo.TBL_FACT_SALES_LWWKS 
GROUP BY  
    LOC_LOC_ID
```

Comment: If i am not wrong then you can do group by LOC_LOC_ID

Comment: No need to do select distinct, the group by returns no duplicates!

Comment: Can you and a sample dataset and the desired output from that sample so that we can understand whether you want every location id and the less of the two: sales value and sales qty - or - you want the location ids that has both: the lowest sales value and the lowest sales qty from among all the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `group by` query up in a derived table. Then use a `case` expression to return the minimum:

```
select s, case when v < q then v else q end
from
(
    SELECT LOC_LOC_ID as S, 
           MIN(LWWKS_TOTAL_SALES_VAL) as V, 
           MIN(LWWKS_TOTAL_SALES_QTY) as Q
    FROM 
    Apollo.dbo.TBL_FACT_SALES_LWWKS 
    GROUP BY LOC_LOC_ID
) dt
```

Alternatively, depending on what OP is asking for:

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT LOC_LOC_ID as S, 
           MIN(LWWKS_TOTAL_SALES_VAL) as V, 
           MIN(LWWKS_TOTAL_SALES_QTY) as Q
    FROM 
    Apollo.dbo.TBL_FACT_SALES_LWWKS 
    GROUP BY LOC_LOC_ID
)
select distinct s, v, q
from cte
where v = (select min(v) from cte)
   or q = (select min(q) from cte)
```

Comment: This outputs location id and the lesser of `sales value` and `sales qty`, which is neat. It might help for the OP to clarify if he wants that, or if he wants the location id who has both: lowest sales value among all records and lowest sales quantity among all records.

Comment: @zedfoxus, yeah, perhaps I misread the question. It's not very clear what OP wants.